# Angular2 problems testing interceptor that extends HTTP module

Tags: angular, testing, dependency-injection, jasmine

I am currently building an Angular2 application that I am in the middle of writing tests for but I have come across an issue I cannot seem to resolve when creating the test module.

I have created a custom class that extends the Angular2 HTTP module and works as an interceptor. This class is responsible for authentication logic and other similar things.

Here is the HttpInterceptor class. This is used instead of the Angular2 HTTP core class and is simply an extension of it:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { GlobalEventsManager } from "./globalEventsManager.service";
import { messages } from "../helpers/messages";

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {
    constructor(
        backend: ConnectionBackend,
        defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
        public _authService: AuthService,
        public _globalEventsManager: GlobalEventsManager
    ) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return super.request(url, options).catch(res => {
            if(res.statusCode === 401) {
                console.log('expired');
            }
        });
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        var obsStream = super.request(url, options);
        obsStream.subscribe((data) => {
            var JSONParsedRes = JSON.parse(data._body);
            if(JSONParsedRes.statusCode) {
                if(JSONParsedRes.statusCode == 401) {
                    this._globalEventsManager.showNavBar.emit(false);
                    this._authService.logout({message: messages.messages.auth.tokenExpired, title:messages.titles.auth.tokenExpired});
                }
            }
        });
        return obsStream;
    }

    handleError() {
        console.log('error');
    }
}
```

Here is the service I am trying to test:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { Product } from "../classes/Product";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { routes } from "../routes";
import { StringHelper } from "../helpers/StringHelper";
import { HttpHelper } from "../helpers/HttpHelper";
import { HttpInterceptor } from "./HttpInterceptor.service";

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    public emitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    private APIUrl:String;

    constructor(
        private _http: HttpInterceptor
    ) {

    }

    getProduct(id:number): Observable<Product> {
        let headers = HttpHelper.createAuthorizationHeader(true, false);
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http
            .get(routes.api.products  + '/' + id, options)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    /**
     * Get all products
     * return Observable
     */
    getProducts(filters:Object): Observable<Product[]> {
        let headers = HttpHelper.createAuthorizationHeader(true, false);
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http
            .get(routes.api.products + StringHelper.convertVarsToString(filters), options)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    editProduct(payload) {
        let headers = HttpHelper.createAuthorizationHeader(true, false);
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        payload['_method'] = 'PUT';
        return this._http
            .post(routes.api.products + '/' + payload.product.id, payload, options)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    /**
     * Add products to EventEmitter stream
     */
    public emitProducts(products): void {
        this.emitter.emit(products);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am dependency injecting the HttpInterceptor class instead of the base Http one in order to use the custom logic included in my Interceptor. This works fine and the application runs as expected. The issue I am having is when I try to configure my testing module to use this HttpInterceptor class an error is thrown. Here is my testing module:

```
import { ProductService } from "../../services/product.service";
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { HttpModule, Http, BaseRequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { MockBackend } from "@angular/http/testing";
import {HttpInterceptor} from "../../services/HttpInterceptor.service";
import {AuthService} from "../../services/auth.service";
import {GlobalEventsManager} from "../../services/globalEventsManager.service";

describe('Service: productService', () => {
    let prodService: ProductService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpModule],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: HttpInterceptor,
                    useFactory: (mockBackend, options, _authService, _globalEventsManager) => {
                        return new HttpInterceptor(mockBackend, options, _authService, _globalEventsManager);
                    },
                    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions, AuthService, GlobalEventsManager]
                },

                MockBackend,
                BaseRequestOptions,
                ProductService
            ]
        });

    });
});
```

I am aware that I need to provide the HttpInterceptor class into the configureTestingModule method in order for this test to work. Unfortunately, this causes an the error though. As you can see I am using useFactory to create an instance of the HttpInterceptor myself and providing all dependencies that needs as well (MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions, AuthService, GlobalEventsManager). I am not sure why this is causing an error?

I have played around a bit and when I change the dependendy in the ProductService constructor from:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    public emitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    private APIUrl:String;

    constructor(
        private _http: HttpInterceptor
    ) {

    }
```

to this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    public emitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    private APIUrl:String;

    constructor(
        private _http: Http
    ) {

    }
```

And then provide the core Http module in the test module as shown here, the testing module works with no error.

```
{
                    provide: Http,
                    useFactory: (mockBackend, options) => {
                        return new Http(mockBackend, options);
                    },
                    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
                },
```

This means there is an issue injecting an instance of my HttpInterceptor class into the testing module and I can't figure out why. Can anyone see why this will be happening?